# How to see all flagged emails from all folders in a single place in Outlook.com?

Tags: outlook.com

I used to see all my flagged emails (similar to how you can search for started items in Gmail) from all my subfolders at the top of my inbox like this:

[image]

But, now, that is gone. The only way to see all the flagged items now is to go to each individual folder :

[image]

But this is tedious as I have hundreds of folders - each with thousands of mails and dozens of flagged emails dating from 1997 (yes, back when this was Hotmail/MSN).

How can I see all my flagged emails together now? There [used to be a search feature](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/oemail-osearch/flagged-emails-no-longer-searchable/67035659-7b3c-490b-a318-b15495e17971) to see all flagged emails but that does not work now either. There also used to be a Microsoft Tasks (https://outlook.live.com/owa/?realm=msn.com&path=/tasks) which used to be able to show flagged emails but now it just redirects to Microsoft ToDo which does not show Outlook flagged emails.

Note: Please do not ask me to switch to Gmail or download Microsoft Outlook - I am talking very specifically about Outlook.com website. How do I see all flagged emails from all subfolders in a single place either via search or some special UI or at the top like before?

Answer (score 9):

You may set the search scope to "All Folders" or "All Mailboxes" and type the string below:

IsFlagged:yes

[image]

Comment: Can I bookmark this search?

Comment: I am afraid we cannot. In Outlook client, it's supported to create a search folder, but this feature is not available to outlook.com.

Comment: How about in the Outlook mobile app? This search does not work there ... how do I see all flagged emails on my phone?

Comment: See available filter criteria here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/search-mail-and-people-in-outlook-com-88108edf-028e-4306-b87e-7400bbb40aa7

Answer (score 1):

**Update Feb 2021**

One can now use filter dropdown from Inbox, to easily view the flagged emails.

[image]

Comment: This only works for a single folder.

Answer (score -1):

Use this URL https://to-do.live.com/tasks/flagged
Even though Flagged Emails no longer appear on the left hand side on to-do.live.com you can add "/flagged" to the URL to see them as below.

[image: To Do live showing flagged emails]

Comment: Please edit your response to provide an answer rather than just a link. (Links tend to fail given time.)

Comment: The link is the answer. Microsoft do not give you a menu option to get to the flagged emails so you have to click on the URL link I have added or maybe in the future add "/flagged" to the URL used to access To-Do, I'm not sure how to make it any clearer??

Comment: Explain what needs to be done, step-by-step. The link simply goes to the download page for ToDo.