# Search for flagged emails from the Outlook search bar/field (Ctrl+E)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search, email-filter

I initially posted this on the [Microsoft Answers site](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_win10-mso_2013_release/search-for-flagged-emails-from-the-outlook-search/1c35bc24-fa83-4267-aee4-6f9c4145bd9f).

I like typing complex search criteria into the Outlook 2013 search bar rather than navigating the GUI and buttons to create a query. The syntax for the search bar is exemplified here:

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/learn-to-narrow-your-search-criteria-for-better-searches-in-outlook-d824d1e9-a255-4c8a-8553-276fb895a8da?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us
- https://www.msoutlook.info/question/boolean-search-with-multiple-criteria

What is the syntax for flagged messages? Neither of the following seems to work:

- flagged:yes
- flag:yes

Thanks.

P.S. My experience thus far is that the search bar/field syntax is the same for Outlook desktop apps and web apps.  If there is an answer to this, I will be using it for both methods of email access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using "IsFlagged:yes" worked for me on desktop Outlook.

Viewed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1371609/how-to-see-all-flagged-emails-from-all-folders-in-a-single-place-in-outlook-com)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks!  It works for both the Outlook desktop client and when using a browser to access Office 365 email.

Comment: worked on linux ubuntu 22 > Edge > Outlook Web from a company

Answer (score 1):

From the [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/learn-to-narrow-your-search-criteria-for-better-searches-in-outlook-d824d1e9-a255-4c8a-8553-276fb895a8da?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) you provided, the criterias below allow the search for flagged emails:

```
due:last week                  Items that are flagged for follow up a due date.
followupflag:follow up         Items that are flagged using the Follow Up flag.
hasflag:true                   Items that are flagged for follow up.
```

You can also use `followupflag:followup flag`

Comment: Geez, I'm an idiot.  I normally would do the obvious things like search for the word "flag".  I don't know how I could have overlooked that.  Should I delete the question?

Comment: @user2153235 Having criteria flag or flagged would make more sense. Keep the question as I didn't know the answer before reading your question. Others might have the same issue.